# Is there a way to view all your old Miiverse drawings?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, miiverse

On Miiverse, the only drawings that appear in my profile are the four most recent. Is there a way to see older ones without digging through the Activity Feed?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to go to your profile, and click posts. It'll take you to old posts you've done.